# UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server with Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

Error in opening new driver window:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

server log:

```
Forwarding newSession on session null to remote
```

I am running following code on linux:

```
driver= new RemoteWebDriver((new URL( "http://"+ip+":5555/wd/hub")), capability);
```

My hub-node already up and running. Then why i am getting this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

and the server log...

```
Forwarding newSession on session null to remote
```

...implies that the *Selenium Grid Hub* / *Selenium Grid Node* wasn't properly initiated/started. As a result a `null session` was forwarded to the *RemoteWebDriver*.

---

Some more information regarding the versions of the binaries which you have used interms of *Selenium* server/client, *WebDriver* variant /version and *WebBrowser* variant /version and the commands you have used to initiate the *Selenium Grid Hub* / *Selenium Grid Node* would have helped us to debug your issue in a easier way.

However this issue can happen due to multiple factors as follows:

- You are using the *uri* `5555/wd/hub`, so ensure that *Selenium Grid Hub* is initiated on port **5555**.
- You may opt to replace the `capability` argument with an instance of `Options` class as follows:

  ```
  DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
  caps.setCapability("browser", "chrome");
  //seting the required capabilities
  ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options.merge(caps);
  WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver((new URL( "http://"+ip+":5555/wd/hub")), options);
  ```
- You can find a relevant discussion in [Remote WebDriver UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49492697/remote-webdriver-unreachablebrowserexception-could-not-start-a-new-session/49493787#49493787)
- This issue is frequently observed with *GeckoDriver/Selenium/Mozilla* due to version mismatch of the binaries you are using. As a thumb rule always follow the configuration matrix from the [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

- You can find a relevant discussion in [WebDriverException: Message: newSession with GeckoDriver Firefox v65 and Selenium through Python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558321/webdriverexception-message-newsession-with-geckodriver-firefox-v65-and-seleniu/54578579#54578579)